# filling in the initializing data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose and setting up schema for users as follows:

```
var users=new mongoose.Schema({
username:String,
password:String,
type:String
});
var User=mongoose.model('user',users);
```

**Now i need this to have a initial row with values as admin,admin,admin
How to do this?**

I am using express server to verify a user like this

```
app.post("/verifyLogin",function(request,response){
var usr=request.body.username;
var pass=request.body.password;
//VERIFICATION FROM DATABASE CODE GOES HERE
});
```

P.S I am new to mongodb/document-based data storage. Until now i used to work with phpmyadmin and insert data directly from the interface provided.

**WHAT I TRIED:**
i made a temp post handler like this

```
app.post("/initialize/database",function(request,response){
var user=new userModel({username:'admin',password:'password', type:'admin'});
user.save(function(err){
if(!err){return console.log('created')}else{console.log(err)}
return response.send(user);
});
})
```

and then in the console did this:

```
jQuery.post('/initialize/database',function(data){console.log(data)})
```

Don't know whether this is the best approach or not :(

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Now i need this to have a initial row with values as admin,admin,admin How to this? PLEASE READ THE POST CAREFULLY. ITS MENTIONED THERE.

Comment: Ah, now it's in bold. I was confused by the "//VERIFICATION FROM DATABASE CODE GOES HERE". Answer coming.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I find it easiest to enter initialization data from the terminal.

```
$ mongo
> use database-name
> db.users.insert({ username: 'admin', password: 'admin', type: 'admin' })
```

That would work for simply getting things going, but I forbid you to store plain-text passwords in the database when in production. To implement hashing and to use node instead of the terminal you could create a route for creating a new user instead. Something like:

```
app.post("/signup",function(request,response){
  var usr = request.body.username,
      pass = request.body.password;

  somePasswordHashingAlgoritm(pass, function (hashedPassword) {
    User.insert({
      username: usr,
      password: hashedPassword,
      type: 'admin'
    });
  });
});
```

Even better would be to implement a pre-save hook in mongoose, but that's the subject for another topic. If you don't want others to sign up to your site, just remove that code when you've created yourself.

Comment: see my edit. I guess i am on the right path. is there a way in mongoose to see the current data without writing another function?

Comment: That looks like more or less what i suggested, and it should work. How do you mean see the current data? something like `User.find({}, function(err, users) { console.log(users); });`?

Comment: can we do this on terminal?

Comment: Absolutely. Choose the correct db as above and enter `db.users.find()` to show all entries. You might find it useful to read the [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/crud/) even if you're using mongoose.